# Why is kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality marked "deprecated" in iOS SDK 6?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, echo-cancellation

from `AudioUnitProperties.h`:

```
 @constant      kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality
 @discussion        Scope: Global
                    Value Type: UInt32
                    Access: read/write
                DEPRECATED. Sets the quality of the voice processing unit. Quality values
                are comprised between 0 (lowest) and 127 (highest).
```

Any ideas what is the reason for deprecating this and if there's anything new to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the tech note about this setting (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1683/_index.html) it talks about using a lower value setting for lower powered devices.

I would assume that this has been deprecated because, by this time, all the devices that iOS supports are powerful enough to handle the high quality setting, removing the need to lower the value.